# How to sum values from one index to another in pyspark with group by

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a **spark** dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dt = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'], 
                   'delta': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'pos': [2,0,0,1,2,1,2,0,0,1],
                   'index': [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4]})
```

I would like to sum the `delta`s from `pos==2` until `pos==1`, for all the times that this occurs, `by id`

So I would like a column to the **spark** dataframe that will look like this:

```
[6, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0]
```

Explanation of result:

- 6 -> for `id` `'a'`, find the first `pos==2` and sum all the `delta`s until (not including) the next `pos==1`, so 1+2+3 =6
- 0 this is not in `pos==2`
- 0 this is not in `pos==2`
- 0 this is not in `pos==2`
- 4 -> for `id` `'a'`, find the next `pos==2` and sum all the `delta`s until (not including) the next `pos==1`, so just 4
- 21 - > for `id` `'b'`, find the first `pos==2` and sum all the `delta`s until (not including) the next `pos==1`, so 7+8+9=24

Any ideas how I can do that efficiently in pyspark ?

**EDIT**

The dataframe is order by `index` and `id`

Comment: window functions?

Comment: @chlebek I am confused on how to use the window function on this context

Comment: Can i order the dataframe with the `delta` column?

Comment: @cronoik I edited my question. the dataframe is ordered by `index` and `id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments you are looking for a way to apply a [window function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window). You need to create an addtional id which allows you to partition your data to calculate the [sum](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sum) of your `delta` row. PLease have a look at the commented example below:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([
                            ('a', 1, 2, 1),
                            ('a', 2, 0, 2),
                            ('a', 3, 0, 3),
                            ('a', 4, 1, 4),
                            ('a', 5, 2, 5),
                            ('a', 6, 1, 6),
                            ('b', 7, 2, 1),
                            ('b', 8, 0, 2),
                            ('b', 9, 0, 3),
                            ('b',10,1,4)
                        ],
                        ['id', 'delta', 'pos', 'index']
                    )

w1 = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('index')
w2 = Window.partitionBy('id', 'subgroup2').orderBy(F.desc('index'))

#apply a subgroup ID to each pos == 2 value
df = df.withColumn("subgroup", F.when(F.col('pos') == 2, F.monotonically_increasing_id()))
df.show()

#forward-fill the subgroup ID to following rows except of rows containing with pos == 1
df = df.withColumn('subgroup2', F.when(F.col('pos') != 1, F.last('subgroup', True).over(w1.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,0))))
df.show()

#calculate the sum for each subgroup ID
df = df.withColumn('deltaSum', F.when(F.col('pos') == 2, F.sum('delta').over(w2)))
df.sort('id', 'index').show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+---+-----+----------+
| id|delta|pos|index|  subgroup|
+---+-----+---+-----+----------+
|  a|    1|  2|    1|         0|
|  a|    2|  0|    2|      null|
|  a|    3|  0|    3|      null|
|  a|    4|  1|    4|      null|
|  a|    5|  2|    5|         1|
|  a|    6|  1|    6|      null|
|  b|    7|  2|    1|8589934592|
|  b|    8|  0|    2|      null|
|  b|    9|  0|    3|      null|
|  b|   10|  1|    4|      null|
+---+-----+---+-----+----------+

+---+-----+---+-----+----------+----------+
| id|delta|pos|index|  subgroup| subgroup2|
+---+-----+---+-----+----------+----------+
|  b|    7|  2|    1|8589934592|8589934592|
|  b|    8|  0|    2|      null|8589934592|
|  b|    9|  0|    3|      null|8589934592|
|  b|   10|  1|    4|      null|      null|
|  a|    1|  2|    1|         0|         0|
|  a|    2|  0|    2|      null|         0|
|  a|    3|  0|    3|      null|         0|
|  a|    4|  1|    4|      null|      null|
|  a|    5|  2|    5|         1|         1|
|  a|    6|  1|    6|      null|      null|
+---+-----+---+-----+----------+----------+

+---+-----+---+-----+----------+----------+--------+
| id|delta|pos|index|  subgroup| subgroup2|deltaSum|
+---+-----+---+-----+----------+----------+--------+
|  a|    1|  2|    1|         0|         0|       6|
|  a|    2|  0|    2|      null|         0|    null|
|  a|    3|  0|    3|      null|         0|    null|
|  a|    4|  1|    4|      null|      null|    null|
|  a|    5|  2|    5|         1|         1|       5|
|  a|    6|  1|    6|      null|      null|    null|
|  b|    7|  2|    1|8589934592|8589934592|      24|
|  b|    8|  0|    2|      null|8589934592|    null|
|  b|    9|  0|    3|      null|8589934592|    null|
|  b|   10|  1|    4|      null|      null|    null|
+---+-----+---+-----+----------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: awesome solution!! i am slightly confused in one scenario. What if there is no matching 1 for a 2 in a group? for example , if i change the last row in the sample dataframe to ```` b   10   9   4 ````. I see that it still gives 34. Say if the sum must happen only if there is a matching 1- is there a simple way?

Comment: Yes there is. You can simply forward fill also the rows which contain 1 (just quick and dirty (there are plenty of ways) after you have calculated `delatsum`) and check if each partition contains 2 and 1 --> if not deltasum = null.